# C++ - How to get structure last member type and a way to access it from existing object?

Tags: c++, templates, types, member

Is there any way I can get class last member type and possibly some-way to access it from existing object (pointer to class member). I need this for my own implementation of new and delete built-in operators.

Any ideas how can I check this?

What I want to do basically:

```
struct S
{
    int b;
    int arr[];
} ;

struct S1
{
    double d;
} ;

last_member_of<S1>::type //type of 'S1::d' - 'double'

last_member_of<S>::type //type of 'S::arr' - 'int []'

last_member_of<S>::value // 'S::*' pointing to 'S::arr'

last_member_of<S1>::value // 'S1::*' pointing to 'S1::d'
```

*The idea is that if the last member is flexible array (I know it's not supported officially by ISO C++ but who cares when most compilers do actually support it) - my re-defined operator will be able to allocate/deallocate additional storage for it, automatically invoking all constructors and destructors.*

Comment: [boost fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/) may help. or turning your structure into `std::tuple`.

Comment: I don't know it's name. Class can be any type.

Comment: Your idea is wrong, as reallocate is

Comment: @Dieter Lücking Can you explain why?

Comment: @Jarod42 Any different way without using 3rd-Party library?

Comment: Any ideas? I really need this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what to do for the *technical* aspect, assuming POD item type for the array:

```
struct S
{
    int b;
    int arr[1];

    auto operator new( size_t const size, int const n )
        -> void*
    {
        return ::operator new( size + (n-1)*sizeof( int ) );
    }

    void operator delete( void* p )
    {
        ::operator delete( p );
    }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    auto pS = new( 42 ) S;
    // USe it.
    delete pS;
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

For a general facility, just generalize this. E.g. you can pass the item type of the flexible array as template argument. There's no need to automate just about everything: explicit is good, implicit is bad.

---

Having said all this, for the *practical*, just use a `std::vector` in there.

---

Addendum:
The OP asked for a direct solution, and I had time to code one up. Well, except that I have not addressed the issue of constructor arguments for the non-array part, or in *general* for the array items, or `const` accessors. Hint to the OP about arguments: `std::forward` is your friend.

Again, all that this buys wrt. using a `std::vector` is

- A particular known memory layout, e.g. to suit some existing C function.
- A single dynamic allocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>   // std::function
#include <memory>       // std::unique_ptr, std::default_delete
#include <new>          // std::operator new( size_t, void* )
#include <stddef.h>     // size_t
#include <stdexcept>    // std::exception, std::runtime_error
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string>       // std::string

namespace cppx {
    using std::function;
    using std::string;
    using std::unique_ptr;
    using std::runtime_error;

    auto fail( string const& s ) -> bool { throw runtime_error( s ); }

    class Non_copyable
    {
    private:
        using This_class = Non_copyable;
        This_class& operator=( This_class const& ) = delete;
        Non_copyable( This_class const& ) = delete;

    public:
        Non_copyable() {}
        Non_copyable( This_class&& ) {}
    };

    template< class Common_data, class Item >
    class Flexible_array
        : public Non_copyable
    {
    template< class T > friend class std::default_delete;
    private:
        union Start_of_array
        {
            Item first_item;
            char dummy;

            ~Start_of_array() {}
            Start_of_array(): dummy() {}
        };

        int                     size_;
        Common_data             data_;
        Start_of_array          items_;

        // Private destructor prevents non-dynamic allocation.
        ~Flexible_array()
        {
            for( int i = size_ - 1; i >= 0; --i )
            {
                p_item( i )->~Item();
            }
        }

        Flexible_array( int const size ): size_( size ) {}

        // Private allocation function prevents client code dynamic allocation.
        // It also servers the purpose of allocating the right size for the array.
        static auto operator new( size_t const n_bytes, int const n )
            -> void*
        { return ::operator new( n_bytes + (n - 1)*sizeof( Item ) ); }

        // Matching operator delete for the case where constructor throws.
        static void operator delete( void* const p, int )
        { ::operator delete( p ); }

        // General operator delete.
        static void operator delete( void* const p )
        { ::operator delete( p ); }

    public:
        auto size() const           -> int              { return size_; }
        auto data()                 -> Common_data&     { return data_; }
        auto p_item( int const i )  -> Item*            { return &items_.first_item + i; }
        auto item( int const i )    -> Item&            { return *p_item( i ); }


        void destroy() { delete this; }

        static auto create( int const size, function< void( int id, void* p_storage ) > construct )
            -> Flexible_array*
        {
            unique_ptr< Flexible_array > p_flex{ new( size ) Flexible_array( size ) };
            for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            {
                try
                {
                    construct( i, p_flex->p_item( i ) );
                }
                catch( ... )
                {
                    p_flex->size_ = i;
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return p_flex.release();
        }

        static auto create( int const size, Item const& default_value )
            -> Flexible_array*
        { return create( size, [&]( int, void* p ) { ::new( p ) Item( default_value ); } ); }

        static auto create( int const size )
            -> Flexible_array*
        { return create( size, [&]( int, void* p ) { ::new( p ) Item(); } ); }
    };
}  // namespace cppx

struct X
{
    int id;

    ~X() { std::clog << "X " << id << " destroyed\n"; }

    X( int const i )
        : id( i )
    {
        if( i == 5 ) { cppx::fail( "Intentional failure of X 5 construction" ); }
        std::clog << "X " << id << " created\n";
    }

    X( X const& other )
        : id( other.id )
    {
        std::clog << "X " << id << " copy-created\n";
    }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        using Flex = cppx::Flexible_array< int, X >;
        unique_ptr<Flex> const p{ Flex::create(
            7 ,
            X( 42 )     // or e.g. "[]( int i, void* p ) { ::new( p ) X( i ); }"
            ) };
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << "\n";
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: OK nice but I also would like to see a direct answer to my question. If possible without using 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: I would be really happy if you can answer it.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Done. I needed some brain/coding exercise. Just be aware that if this is homework, as seems likely, then you learn less by asking for solutions rather than doing it yourself and asking for code review.

Comment: I smell you actually over-done yourself. It's not about a homework and I needed exact solution. I hardly think that this code get last member type or does anything closely to what I want. Can you provide more detailed explanation of it's purpose?

Comment: @FISOCPP: It's a flexible array, with support for C++ construction of items. Getting the address of a last member was seen as an erroneously identified sub-goal of that. But if you really want it, it is as simple as just **taking that address**, when the name is known, or else practically impossible in formally portable code. Jeez.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Hm, re-reading your question, in light of your comments here, apparently you're conflating `new`-*expressions* with the `new` *operator*. A `new` *expression*, like `new T(1, 2, 3)`, calls an allocation function and then constructs a `T` object in the obtained storage. A `new` *operator*, like `auto operator new( size_t ) -> void*`, is an allocation function that's called by `new` expressions. You can overload/override an allocation function, as in this answer. But you can not overload or override `new` expressions. They do what they always do.

Comment: However - I can't create my own ;). Which won't be called 'new' but will do the same job. I've actually made it - and I can say that it's working and it's far better then the existing one. But I also would like to add this cool functionality never seen before. However now I see it is very hard to be done.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get the last struct member automatically.
It's easy to understand this, if you realize that the end of a struct may have padding: there is simply no way to know if the end is just padding or a value:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

struct A1 {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t x1;
}; // 3 bytes padding at the end

struct A2 {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t x1;
    uint8_t x2;
}; // 2 bytes padding at the end

struct A3 {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t x1;
    uint8_t x2;
    uint8_t x3;
}; // 1 byte padding at the end

struct A4 {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t x1;
    uint8_t x2;
    uint8_t x3;
    uint8_t x4;
}; // no padding

int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(A1) == 8);
    static_assert(sizeof(A2) == 8);
    static_assert(sizeof(A3) == 8);
    static_assert(sizeof(A4) == 8);
    
    static_assert(offsetof(A1, x1) == 4);
    static_assert(offsetof(A2, x2) == 5);
    static_assert(offsetof(A3, x3) == 6);
    static_assert(offsetof(A4, x4) == 7);
}
```